# What are the ramifications of an AI Bot passing a legal competency test?

Tags: ethics, artificial-intelligence

> The criteria for judging competence to stand trial was articulated in
> the 1960 Supreme Court decision Dusky v. United States. Dusky states
> that to be competent to stand trial, a defendant must have a “rational
> and factual understanding of the proceedings” and be able to consult
> with his or her attorney with a “reasonable degree of rational
> understanding”

Competence Assessment for Standing Trial for Defendants with Mental ... https://criminal-justice.iresearchnet.com/forensic-psychology/competence-assessment-for-standing-trial-for-defendants-with-mental-retardation-castmr/

Both the CAST*MR and the Woodcock-Johnson tests have been used to establish legal competence.

Recently, GPT-4 passed the bar exam: GPT-4 Passes the Bar Exam | Illinois Institute of Technology https://www.iit.edu/news/gpt-4-passes-bar-exam

Would the ability of an AI Bot to pass a legal competency test have any philiosophical ramifications?

Based on the current Supreme Court definition, the possibility of an AI Bot being competent to stand trial is not far off. Is the ability to create an autonomous legal entity that can stand trial on the horizon?

Or is the current Supreme Court criteria woefully outdated given the current technology?

Comment: Those tests weren't created to test AIs, so an AI "passing" them doesn't indicate it has legal autonomous competency.

Comment: @curiousdannii I agree but it is a step closer. Corporations are an example of a "legal person". If an AI Bot can be declared a legal person and is competent to stand trial, how does that affect the notions of liability and responsibility?

Comment: Suppose a human bad actor created an AI like GPT for a nefarious purpose, like harassment campaigns, disinformation, ... should we blame the AI and leave the human bad actor go free, or should we go after the human bad actor behind the AI? What punishment would you issue on a wayward AI? Turn it off? Retrain it? Who would pay for that? Maybe the money angle is important, at the end of the day, many cases are settled for money --- but AI's don't have any money. Victims's lawyers would try to identify the human deep pockets and go after those.

Comment: @Frank The ability of AI to learn means it's always evolving. How will a truly autonomous AI decision be distinguished from a human coding mistake?

Comment: @StevanV.Saban it's always evolving if you let it learn constantly. Many models are trained once and then used for scoring/inference without "evolving" till their next re-training, if ever. I think with ML/AI systems, there's no risk of human coding mistake. It's all deported to what training data you feed the model. "Bugs" in that context are feeding the "wrong" data to the model to train it. Actually - that's a very good point - you can always point to the human selection of the training data as responsible for model "errors".

Comment: A lotta stuff has happened here.//Ok, but everybody knows that!//You don't seem impressed.//You got that right! Of course a lotta stuff has happened here! Anybody could tell us that!!//You look disappointed!//Ya think!!

Comment: What do ya suppose the world is like? Secondly,  what is a legally well-informed AI? Any ideas?

Comment: @Frank - Like you said law has limits enforcing remedies against AI software or personified robots. Basic penalties for crimes are community service, fines, and imprisonment. Civil remedies are injunctions or damages (award of money). Jurisdiction pertains to court authority to decide the subject matter, to coerce defendants in a region, and to seize property via police force. AI could transact money by lawful or unlawful means. See Marvel MCU scene https://youtu.be/PTbcaC0mGY8?t=108 the fictional emotionally unstable AI Ultron sends money to a criminal's bank account over computer networks.

Comment: The question seems to be about law, not philosophy, and thus seems off-topic here.  Also the SCOTUS ruling is a criteria, not a definition. It does not define what can stand trial, it adds a restriction on top of others to what can stand trial. GPT based AIs are still a far shot of being able to do complex logic reliably.

Comment: Also it's click-baity to say GPT passed a bar exam. The precise narrative is that "humans scored sufficient points in a simulated bar exam to pass by using GPT generated answers." It's a mouthful, but on a philosophic forum that precision can be expected.

Comment: GPT does not have a “rational and factual understanding of the proceedings”, it successfully produces a stream of words that will answer a given question based on massive input of similar texts (in that case, a test question). It's like a chess program who, having in its DB a massive amount of recorded chess games can succesfully predict the next move of a human player would do (ie, you tell it "1. e4,e5; 2. Nf3, Nc6;" it can reply "3. Bb5"), but have absolutely no understanding of the rules or even the basic concepts of chess. AI is still far from being able to stand trial.

Comment: @armand The tests I mentioned are designed for the mentally challenged in determining competency for trial. So it's a test for the minimum required for a human to stand trial. If a chatBot passes a test like this, what happens? Are the tests rewritten to ensure a chatBot won't pass or will laws change to ensure a Chatbot never takes that test. Does that devalue humans?

Comment: The point is GPT does not pass the test because it understands what a legal procedure is, but because it peeks at other people's answers, so to speak. Humans who take the test can't do that, they go with their own memory. As of now GPT wont express a willingness to sue someone or defend its own rights in front of a court, because it has no concept of such a thing and no will of its own. At best it shows that some kind of psy expert interview is necessary to make sure the subject is not just mindlessly repeating law books it has read previously (which is probably already the case).

Comment: In such matter of loop holes the judge's common sense should apply. That's why we have judges and don't just mindlessly apply the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the ability of an AI Bot to pass a legal competency test have any philiosophical ramifications?

No. Politicians and judges of diverse can make all sorts of absurd laws. Philosophy does generally not care, and does not follow legal definitions. So in itself if there is a country in which AI passes some legal criteria to count as cattle, and another country in which AI passes legally as deity, and another country in which AI legally becomes a fart, philosophy does not care.

It's just laws, they can be changed.

Comment: All developments in AI challenge the notions of what is a uniquely human thought and what intelligence is solely in the domain of humans. Philosophy cares about this.

Comment: Sure, but the OP asked about a legal process specifically, and i answered specifically to that. The ability of an agent to pass any given legal test depends on legal test, not on the specifics of the agent. We can define a legal test that a potato passes, that does not make potatoes more interesting to philosophy, it would just be a silly application of law.

Comment: "We can define a legal test that a potato passes, that does not make potatoes more interesting to philosophy". If a potato passes a test meant to determine human competency, then humans become less interesting to philosophy. Humans are devalued. This is simply Industrial Revolution 2.0 instead of man vs. machine in physical skill and strength it's man vs machine in intellect.  The Industrial Revolution certainly influenced modern philosophy. The parable of John Henry is a simple example.

Comment: No, humans do not become less interesting to philosophy just because some judge of some court on some island makes a bad law that happens to include potatos. The creation of such a silly law changes neither the nature of the potato nor of man, it changes strictly nothing. You construct meaning and importance where there is none. Certainly I do not wish for every question "blablabla AI blablabla" to be treated as if this was very philoisophical. Philosophical questions about AI can be asked, but not every question with "AI" in it is philosophical.

Comment: Thanks. I believe you are correct. There are no real philosophical questions regarding AI at this time. It's simply an advanced system of computation. Any impact on society now is a socialogy issue or a trivial legal issue. Any fears AI brings up are psychology issues. Any issues regarding the science behind AI are computer science engineering issues. The fear plus the varied cross-disciplines involved make it look and feel like a philosophy issue.

Answer (score 0):

Humans could in theory learn to recognize intersubjective autonomous AI machines (human-like robots) as legal persons with rights and duties imposed by statutes or judicial doctrines of law. This would not be limited to the legal concept of competency, but rather, it would depend on how humans perceive human-like robots as a type of cause.

Back in 1990-1991 I took two law school courses, torts and legal philosophy, with Professor Hugh Gibbons. Law, according to Gibbons, is concerned with patterns of human perception. Each human is a willed agent whose experience of **will** is stated as an I-statement: *I am the cause of desired perceptions.* Hugh did not explicate the model in his writing, but implied in the model, is that natural events or the willed actions of other humans can interfere with the will of any individual. Natural events and other humans are joint causes of individual perceptions along with the individual effort to cause desired perceptions. When conditions are favorable the human will may subjectively perceive the self as the sole cause of desired perceptions because under those conditions there are no natural or willed causes interfering with the effectiveness of the will.

According to Gibbons coercion is deliberate interference with the will of a human caused by the willed acts of another person. In his sketch model interference with the will maps to willed agents or to unwilled events in the perception of a willed agent. Law is defined as the justified use of coercion under a claim of right. Gibbons argues that American law is based on an unstated Axiom: *The will of each person is worthy of respect.* This unstated Axiom seems to inform the judicial deliberations and the evolution of the American rule of law.

This paragraph is an effort to incorporate my recollection of Hugh's philosophical views as applied to the American legal institutions. Willed agents have reciprocal rights and duties in the context of social interaction. Animals are not willed agents, in the perception of humans, and therefore do not have rights and duties of a willed agent.  Animals only have rights if a willed agent argues for, and secures, such rights by imposing legal duties on other willed agents. A young human child has an emergent will. The child is learning how to become the cause of desired perceptions in the context of social interactions with other willed agents. American law is paternalistic and imposes duties on willed agents to respect the emerging will of the human child.

In the context where we assume, based on experience, that humans have the capacity for vague or fuzzy pattern recognition, then it would be reasonable to argue that humans cannot make a crisp distinction between human traits and non-human traits. That means anthropomorphism is an inherent property of the human mind. If AI is perceived as animal-like the law might emerge to treat those AI similar to animals. If AI is perceived as child-like the law might emerge to treat those AI similar to a child. If AI is perceived as the intersubjective expression of a willed agent with the capacity for human prudence then the law might emerge to treat those AI as legal persons with rights and duties.

The common law refers to judicial doctrines that evolved in the context of legal disputes in the Anglo-American traditions. As I recall the age of reason is seven in common law and the age of majority is either seventeen or eighteen. The age of reason and majority can be altered by custom or statute within a jurisdiction. The main idea is that if the child is below the age of reason then the law does not hold the child responsible for harm that might otherwise be considered negligent or intentional harms for a person at or above the age of reason. Also if a contract is formed between an adult and an infant, where an infant has not attained the age of majority, the contract might be enforceable against the adult but not against the infant as a matter of law.

There are many sources that discuss the age of reason and the age of majority, but I am at a loss to find a persuasive authority via keyword search. Webster's defines prudence as the ability to govern action by the use of reason. The law as a social institution seems to value prudence, and acts to compensate for harm caused by imprudence, and acts to punish certain acts of imprudence. That is my philosophical interpretation. The age of reason and age of majority pertain to folk psychology - the perception of mental capacities developing from early childhood to adulthood in the typical human. If human-like robots are perceived to express the intersubjective development of prudence, then the law may evolve to treat such robots like maturing human children.

Courts will not enforce a contract made between an infant and an adult due to the assumption of disparity in mental capacity. A contract is a deal or bargain that binds the parties to keep their promises based on mutual consideration (the agreement to exchange items of value under the terms of the deal). Intelligent AI might become a legal person when it has the perceived abilities to act autonomously, to negotiate bargains, and to govern behavior according to our judicial principles of ethical and moral reasoning. However, an AI personality might be treated as a legal non-person for other reasons such as happened to human slaves and other human groups who were excluded from owning property or access to courts.

Based on a tragic real event a parent gives a Crickett rifle to their five year old son. The boy shoots and kills his two year old sister. In law this is homicide, the killing of another, but it is not murder, since the child below age seven cannot act with malice aforethought. In terms of folk psychology, we think it is only natural for a young child to imitate or ape the behavior of adults without yet possessing prudence - the ability to govern action by the use of reason. The homicide or harm caused by young children is interpreted as an innocent tragedy not a moral injury caused by a competent moral agent.

The bottom line is that we look for a competent moral agent similar to an adult with autonomy and prudence in the circumstances of the dispute. If we rule out harm caused by a willed human, or potentially a machine that we infer also implements competent human will, then we would attribute events to non-moral sources of cause. This becomes a problem of pattern recognition based on first order distinction between willed and non-willed sources of cause in the context of prudence - the ability to govern action by the use of reason.

A human legal person is often held responsible for breach of contract; or for negligent supervision of children, or of wild or aggressive animals; or for harm caused by inherently dangerous activities; or for harm caused by the introduction of defective machines into commerce; etc. There are patterns of law, derived from folk psychology, that would be applied to human deployment of AI via reasoning by analogy. An AI robot might be perceived as animal-like, child-like, wild, aggressive, inherently dangerous, or a defective product, etc. There are many implications of AI for disputes under law. The law is often slow to develop on a subject when new issues arise. The operates in part using the methods of factual case study and reasoning by analogy.

Comment: The age of criminal responsibility is 10 in the UK, & 12 in the USA.

Comment: @CriglCragl Seven is the age of reason under traditional common law. As you point out it is not the general rule applied in courts or for definitions of statutory crimes. I intend to edit the post to clarity.

Comment: I can't find any reference to what you mention. Can you give any evidence for 7 as a special age in legal terms? See eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_criminal_responsibility

Comment: @CriglCragl Search for common law age of reason. There should be many sources. As I recall scholars map common law back to judicial rules established as far back as Rome, England, and the United States. I expect this scholarship to be controversial on the historical analysis. I think it is difficult to describe the law (and politics) as the evolving experience and expression of intersubjective folk psychology - but that seems to me to be the foundational context. The study of law made me regard human interactions as modes of self-other communication. Behavior evokes meaning and interpretation.

Comment: "If human-like robots are perceived to express the intersubjective development of prudence, then the law may evolve to treat such robots like maturing human children."  This seems like anthropomorphism. AI is not a child nor is there any sort of maturation process. AI is assembled as a fully mature entity that begins learning when it's turned on. It can pass a bar exam hours after it is turned on and present information as if an adult was "speaking".

Comment: @StevanV.Saban - The question relates to legal competence, and by implication, more broadly, what does it mean to be recognized by humans as a responsible person under the law? Based on the evidence of our senses, if humans do not experience intersubjective human experience, then the individual child would not survive early life. The hyperbole of the fictional drama of baby Tarzan shows that the baby would perish too in the absence of parents or external caregivers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RP4k_SDHR44. If AI mimics patterns of human autonomous and social behavior we will recognize it.